# Zero byte output File in Unix Environment

Tags: shell, unix

Generic question, not specific to any code.
I've come across many times to this problem,
In an Unix environment a job(Script) completed successfully however output files created by the job were all of ZERO bytes. What could be the most probable issue ?

Comment: Is it because the File System is full ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be caused due to below reasons.
1. File system is full. You can use df command to verify the same.

```
sh-4.1$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        72G   25G   44G  36% /
tmpfs           3.8G  4.0K  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1       2.4G   45M  2.2G   2% /boot
/dev/sda5       369G  184G  166G  53% /home
sh-4.1$
```

2. User/Group quota is full.
   You can verify the same using repquota command.